# Parsing HTML with Hpricot & Ruby - getting the innermost html?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, html-parsing, hpricot

I'm looking to parse some old html that has plenty of extraneous tags that could be done with CSS now - `<b>`, `<font>`, etc.  I'm using Hpricot to parse it, but I want to get the innermost "inner_html" - how does one do that with Hpricot?  For example lets say I user Hpricot to grab all the `<table>` elements which I loop through to get the rows and cells, but I want to get the data inside the cells, but they can have no additional tags or things like `<b><font ...>1,000</font></b>` - is there a trick to getting just the "1,000" out?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is completely what you want, but you might want to look at the **inner_text** method.  It will return the same thing as inner_html, except all of the HTML elements will be removed.